# Почему не срабатывает событие отправки формы?

Tags: javascript, события

Есть следующий минимально-воспроизводимый пример:

```
<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="file-input" id="file-label">Выберите файл</label>
</form>

<script>
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
    const fileLabel = document.getElementById('file-label');
        
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        alert("File selected!");
        document.getElementById('upload-form').submit();
    });

    document.getElementById('upload-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Form send!");
    });
</script>
```

Почему в данном случает не отправляется форма/не срабатывает `addEventListener` с аргументом `submit`? Т.е. `alert("File selected!");`  срабатывает, а `alert("Form send");` нет...

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` предотвращает отправку формы.

Comment: `alert("Form send")` не срабатывает потому что нет собственно события `submit` у формы... Кнопку "отправки" не давили... `Enter` в полях не жали... Вот событие и не наступает.

Comment: @Quazimorda, благодарю за комментарий! Закомментил `event.preventDefault();`. Не помогло.

Comment: @ksa, кнопка отправки сознательно не добавлялась. Целью было сделать форму с всего лишь одной кнопкой, чтобы при выборе файлов их загрузка, точнее отправка формы, выполнялась автоматически...без нажатия на кнопку "Отправить". Не понимаю, почему `document.getElementById('upload-form').submit();` не работает. Вроде, все логично, но почему-то не работает! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что вы считаете что метод `submit()` вызывает событие `submit`, что на самом деле не так.

Можно убедиться в этом прочитав пару строк [из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> Этот метод похож, но не идентичен кнопке [<button>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). , который активирует отправку формы. Однако при непосредственном вызове этого метода:
>
> - Событие [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) не инициировано. В частности, обработчик события [`onsubmit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) для данной формы не запускается.
> - [Проверка ограничений](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Constraint_validation) не запускается

Вместо метода `submit`, вы можете использовать метод [`requestSubmit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit#browser_compatibility), который не имеет проблем указанных выше, но [поддерживается только на современных браузерах](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit#browser_compatibility).

Также как указал [@Quazimorda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/293639/quazimorda), метод [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) предотвращает стандартное событие (то-есть отправку формы в данном случае). Используя информацию выше, получается вот такой код:

```html
<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="file-input" id="file-label">Выберите файл</label>
</form>

<script>
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
    const fileLabel = document.getElementById('file-label');
        
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        alert("File selected!");
        const form = document.getElementById('upload-form');
        form[typeof form.requestSubmit !== 'undefined' ? 'requestSubmit' : 'submit']();
    });

    document.getElementById('upload-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        alert("Form send!");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли найти ответ на вопрос!